# Multiple integration with Dirac delta

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, dirac-delta, multiple-integral

I am reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.13059) and trying to solve collision integral. In Appendix A, there is an integral, $$ I^{(n)} = \int \frac{p^2_1\,dp_1 \,p^2_3\,dp_3\,p^2_4\,dp_4}
{2E_12E_32E_4} 2\pi \delta (p_1 − p_3 − p_4)e^{−E_1/T} I_\Omega,$$
where
\begin{align}
I_\Omega 
&=\left( 4\pi \right)^3 \int d^3\lambda \, \frac{\sin p_1\lambda }{p_1\lambda}\frac{\sin p_3\lambda }{p_3\lambda}\frac{\sin p_4\lambda }{p_4\lambda} \\ 
&=\dfrac{32\pi^5}{p_1p_3p_4}\Bigg[\dfrac{\left( p_1-p_3+p_4\right) }{\left| p_1-p_3+p_4\right|}+\frac{(p_1+p_3-p_4) }{| p_1+p_3-p_4|}-\frac{(p_1-p_3-p_4) }{|p_1-p_3-p_4|}-\frac{(p_1+p_3+p_4) }{|p_1+p_3+p_4|}\Bigg].
\end{align}

They get a result $$I^{(n)}=\int \frac{16\pi^6 p_1^2}{E_1}e^{-E_1/T} \, dp_1$$ after integrating out dirac delta. I can't seem to understand how do they remove both $p_3$ and $p_4$ using one delta integral. Also, since all the terms in brackets of $I_\Omega$ are positive, it seems that term goes to zero. Can anyone help?

Note: $E_i$ and $p_i$ are energy and momentum of $i^{th}$ particle and here it is assumed that $m_3 =0$ and $m_4=0$ hence $E_3 = \sqrt{p_{3}^{2}+m_{3}^{2}}=p_{3}
$ & similarly $E_4 = p_4$.

Comment: The "naive" answer is to write it as an iterated integral, say with $p_4$ as your innermost integral, and then evaluate the integral with the $\delta$ as is $p_1, p_3$  are constants. This should work. Properly justifying this and understanding what we mean $\delta(p_1 - p_3 -p_4)$ requires some of the theory of distributions that seems beyond the scope of what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @PhysicalMathematics Yes, when I remove $\delta$ with $p_4$ integration, I seem to get $I_\Omega =0$ which is where I get a problem.

Comment: I just saw your note at the end, which doesn't really make sense, how can we take $p_3, p_4$, which are variables we are integrating over, equal to some fixed values: $E_3, E_4$?

Comment: What I meant was both $m_3 =0$ and $m_4=0 $ So, $E_3= \sqrt{p_{3}^{2}+m_{3}^{2}}=p_{3}$ and $E_{4}=\sqrt{p_{4}^{2}+m_{4}^{2}}=p_{4}$

Comment: So that's not at all clear from the statement of your question. Please make the post mathematically self contained; I mean this might be obvious in the physics context but a mathematician looking at your integral will want to assume that the $E_j$ are just some constants.

Comment: @PhysicalMathematics Thanks, I have edited my question and made it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it should be noted that $p_1,p_3,p_4$ are limited to positive real values (they represent *magnitudes* of momenta). Since the delta function restricts to $p_1=p_3+p_4$, it follows that

$$p_1-p_3+p_4=2p_4\geq 0,\quad p_1+p_3-p_4=2p_3\geq 0,\quad p_1+p_3+p_4=2p_1\geq 0.$$

Therefore for three of the four terms in $I_\Omega$ we have $$\dfrac{p_1-p_3+p_4}{| p_1-p_3+p_4|}=\dfrac{p_1+p_3-p_4}{| p_1+p_3-p_4|}=\dfrac{p_1+p_3+p_4}{| p_1+p_3+p_4|}=1.$$

This leaves the third term in $I_\Omega$, which at first glance seems ill-defined since $p_1-p_3-p_4=0$. But this absolute value arises from the representation $\int\frac{d\lambda}{\lambda p}\sin(\lambda p)=|p|^{-1},$ and thus
$$\frac{p}{|p|}=\int_0^\infty \frac{d\lambda}{\lambda}\sin(\lambda p)\to \int_0^\infty \frac{d\lambda}{\lambda}0=0$$ in the limit $p\to 0^+$.

Combining the above, we see that $I_\Omega=\dfrac{32\pi^5}{p_1p_3p_4}$
on the restriction $p_1=p_3+p_4$. Hence

\begin{align}
I^{(n)} 
&= \int \frac{p^2_1\,dp_1}{2E_1} \frac{p^2_3\,dp_3}{2E_3} \frac{p^2_4\,dp_4}{2E_4}
2\pi \delta (p_1 − p_3 − p_4)e^{−E_1/T} I_\Omega\\
&= \int \frac{p^2_1\,dp_1}{2E_1} \frac{p^2_3\,dp_3}{2E_3} \frac{p^2_4\,dp_4}{2E_4}
2\pi \delta (p_1 − p_3 − p_4) \dfrac{32\pi^5}{p_1p_3p_4}e^{−E_1/T}\\
&= \int \frac{8\pi^6 p_1}{E_1}e^{−E_1/T}\,dp_1 \,dp_3\,dp_4
 \delta (p_1 − p_3 − p_4)
\end{align}
where I've used $E_3=p_3$, $E_4=p_4$.
Eliminating the $p_4$-integral using the delta function yields

$$I^{(n)}=\int_0^\infty \frac{8\pi^6 p_1}{E_1}e^{−E_1/T}\,dp_1\int_0^{p_1}\,dp_3=\int_0^\infty \frac{8\pi^6 p_1^2}{E_1}e^{−E_1/T}\,dp_1.$$
This is *almost* in agreement with the stated result: there's a missing factor of two which I haven't tracked down yet. I'll see what I find.

---

I haven't succeeded in finding the error, and the more checks I do make me suspicious about the original source. In particular, the factor of two would be accounted for if one assumes that $$\frac{p_1-p_3-p_4}{|p_1-p_3-p_4|}\to -1$$ when $p_1=p_3+p_4$ rather than zero (as I have above). But as far as I can tell, this term should genuinely vanish given its integral representation in the Appendix. Beyond that I don't see an obvious explanation, and so I would tentatively propose a mathematical error in the source.

---

After having examined the source material (along with some awareness of the underlying physics) the current conjecture of the OP and myself is that the delta function should actually be $$\delta(E_1-E_3-E_4)=0.$$ This reflects the fact that the constraint should arise from conservation of 4-momentum, which includes energy conservation. With this reading in mind, the behavior of $I_\Omega(p_1,p_3,p_4)$ when subject to this constraint is a bit different and I'll address the terms in pairs. First, note that energy conservation implies $$p_3+p_4=E_3+E_4=E_1=\sqrt{p_1^2+m_1^2}\geq p_1 >0.$$
Since $p_1\geq 0 \geq -p_1$, we conclude that $p_1-p_3-p_4$ and $p_1+p_3+p_4$ have opposite signs. As such, the last two terms in $I_\Omega$ will vanish identically. The analogous question for the remaining two terms are the values of $p_1-p_3+p_4$ and $p_1+p_3-p_4$, with $I_\Omega$ vanishing unless the signs match. But $$(p_1-p_3+p_4)+(p_1+p_3-p_4)=2p_1\geq 0$$ and so cannot both be negative. For both to be positive, we require
\begin{align}
0
&<(p_1-p_3+p_4)(p_1+p_3-p_4)\\
&=p_1^2-(p_3-p_4)^2\\
&=(p_3+p_4)^2-m_1^2-(p_3-p_4)^2\\
&=4p_3 p_4-m_1^2
\end{align}
Thus the terms are both positive if $4p_3p_4>m_1^2$ and we conclude that energy conservation dictates $$I_\Omega(p_1,p_3,p_4)=\dfrac{64\pi^5}{p_1p_3p_4}\theta(4p_3p_4-m_1^2)$$ whenever energy conservation is fulfilled. As such, the complete integral is

$$I^{(n)} 
= \int \frac{p^2_1\,dp_1}{2E_1} \frac{p^2_3\,dp_3}{2E_3} \frac{p^2_4\,dp_4}{2E_4}
2\pi \delta (E_1 − E_3 − E_4)e^{−E_1/T}\dfrac{64\pi^5}{p_1p_3p_4}\theta(4p_3p_4-m_1^2)$$

Since energy conservation dictates $$p_4=E_4=E_1-E_3=\sqrt{p_1^2+m_1^2}-p_3,$$ integrating out $p_4$ first yields

$$I^{(n)} 
= \int \frac{16\pi^6 p_1\,dp_1}{E_1} dp_3 e^{−E_1/T}\theta\Bigg(4p_3\Big[\sqrt{p_1^2+m_1^2}-p_3\Big]-m_1^2\Bigg)$$

The limits for the $p_3$ integral are dictated by the condition

$$4p_3\Big[E_1-p_3\Big]-m_1^2\geq 0$$

which for $p_1,p_3\geq 0$ is equivalent to $$\frac12\left(E_1-p_1\right)\leq p_3\leq \frac12\left(E_1+p_1\right)$$
As such the $p_3$-integral is simply

$$\int_{(E_1-p_1)/2}^{(E_1+p_1)/2} dp_3 = \frac{E_1+p_1}{2}-\frac{E_1-p_1}{2}=p_1$$
and therefore
$$I^{(n)} 
= \int \frac{16\pi^6 p_1^2\,dp_1}{E_1} e^{−E_1/T}$$
as claimed. As a check we consider the integral denoted $I^{(p)}$ in the source material. Then the presence of the factor $U=E_3=p_3$ renders the $p_3$ integral as

$$\int_{(E_1-p_1)/2}^{(E_1+p_1)/2} p_3\,dp_3 = \frac12\left(\frac{E_1+p_1}{2}\right)^2-\frac12\left(\frac{E_1-p_1}{2}\right)^2=\frac12 E_1 p_1$$
and therefore

$$I^{(p)} 
= \int 8\pi^6 p_1^2\,dp_1 e^{−E_1/T}$$
which again matches the source material.

Comment: I understand the steps now. Also, if you check the source, there is another integral with $I^{(n)}$, $I^{(\rho)}$ which seems to have the correct factor of $8 \pi ^{6}$. I will try to find whether it is an error or not.

Comment: Is it possible that $p_{1}-p_{3}-p_{4}=\sqrt{E_{1}^{2}-m^{2}_{1}}-E_{3}-E_{4} <0$ from energy conservation $E_{1}-E_{3}-E_{4}=0$ ? Then third term in $I_\Omega$ would be negative.

Comment: @annoying_noob I think so, yes. They factor their delta function as $$\delta^{4}(p_1-p_3-p_4)=\delta^{3}(\mathbf{p}_1-\mathbf{p}_3-\mathbf{p}_4)\delta(p_1-p_3-p_4).$$ If $p_1,p_3,p_4$ on the LHS are understood as four-vectors rather than magnitudes, then it'd make sense that $E_1-E_3-E_4=0$. That's not great presentation but it would resolve matters. (It's been too long since I've done these kinds of computations, so I'll leave the casework to you.)

Comment: If that is the case, though, this complicates the evaluation of $I_\Omega$. In particular, one now has $$p_1-p_3+p_4=\sqrt{E_1^2-m_1^2}-E_3+E_4$$ which can be positive or negative when $E_1=E_3+E_4$ (and similarly for $p_1+p_3-p_4$). The problem is hopefully still tractable but certainly less trivial.

Comment: Maybe we can use a physical bound that $p_i < p_j+p_k$ for different combinations $i,j,k = 1,3,4$. Is that a valid assumption?

Comment: I think you’re on the right track. Indeed, I _think_ it may be the case that energy conservation forces $I_\Omega$ to vanish unless $$(p_3-p_4)^2<p_1^2=(p_3+p_4)^2-m_1^2$$ which reduces to $4p_3 p_4>m_1^2$. I’m not sure what the physical significance of this condition is: Maybe that one of the outgoing particles is (not) back-scattered? I’ll check the details and edit accordingly when I get a chance.

Comment: @annoying_noob I've now updated my answer accordingly and it indeed reproduces the results in the paper. So aside from them writing $\delta(p_1-p_3-p_4)$ rather than $\delta(E_1-E_3-E_4)$ I think their results are sound.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and clear answer. It didn't turn out to be as trivial as I thought it would be. Also, the paper has used some confusing notations. But their results are indeed correct. Now I have to figure out how to convert these to Bessel functions.

Comment: A substitution like $E_1=m_1\cosh \tau, p_1=m_2\sinh \tau$ will hopefully get you to one of the representations [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32) smoothly. (Though to be honest I'd just do these integrals with Mathematica at this point.)

Comment: Yes, Mathematica is better :) But I just wanted to reproduce these results by hand since I am a beginner. And yes, by taking $E_1=m_1\cosh t$ it was straightforward to convert these integrals to Bessel functions.